# VS-OnLine - Build/Release Error: Config is missing for service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, alm, service-fabric-stateful

I'm trying to create a build and release to a actors service in Visual Studio Online. I already created build and release to anothers services fabric without problem. But with this specific service I getting the error below:

The BuildLayout of the application in E:\SFabric\SP\SP2DS\Fabric\work\ImageBuilderProxy\AppType\SchedulerServiceAppType is invalid. Config is missing for service SchedulerServicePkg.

The first time the release works fine, but after the first version is released, the others releases I got this error.

The others services are Stateless, I dont know why this problem happens and just with this service that is Stateful.

**New Information**

I'm trying to change advantages setting and I got successful sometimes.

[image: Advantage settings]

Even that, I want to know how I do correctly

Comment: What's the result if you build it manually? A thread maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165542/service-fabric-deployment-error-servicemanifest-xml-is-missing-for-service/39223990

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I can't deploy manually, because there is a restriction, but local its works correctly.

This another thread I already saw, but its not exactly my case.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?(Set/add system.debug variable to true)

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, How can I send a private message to you? In the log file there are private information of my company

Comment: You can remove sensitive information, then share the log.

Answer (score 0):

@ Novac - Just noticed a duplicate post on Github addressing this specific issue. More importantly, a member of Azure's Service Fabric Dev team is actively engaged and waiting for your response to his followup questions - ref snip below:
 Currently tracked via GitHub issue:https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/802. Strongly recommend redirecting this conversation to the Github thread/url above.

[image: conversation snip from GitHub]